# kaltura run on standalone machine

Tags: platform, kaltura, centos6.5

I am trying running a kaltura standalone machine, installing a kaltura server on Centos6.5 machine following the instruction tables on

https://github.com/kaltura/platform-install-packages/blob/master/doc/install-kaltura-redhat-based.md

that works fine without error, but here we are, how can i start the kmc and the kac?

i tryed localhost.localdomain/start , localhost.localdomain/kmc but they don't work?

Where am i wrong? Have I to run some particular service?

Answer (score 3):

Does an apache service is started on your server ?
Run sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart

The Kaltura server should be running fine if the installation was successful.

Comment: Thank you, the httpd had failed to start, you right, but i solved this step re-running the kaltura-config-all.sh kaltura-front-config.sh and commenting one row of code on monit.conf.. even one warning to solve but now the kaltura.domainame/start works fine and even the the admin-console and kmc are ok.